# Where to put the classes.txt file and each label txt file for images for YOLOv4

Tags: yolov4

As I used the YOLOv4 following the video tutorial, I could not get the chart.png which I believe should be because of the training has not even started.

Here is the link of my notebook.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1s-eKUoK-qRrVbV3gZid_B1cSgDxd4GmR?usp=sharing

I tried to find the place where I should upload the classes.txt file into google colab VM.
I believe without that file the trainer does not know what the first digit in image label txt files corresponds to.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: on left panel on google colab, there is a 'folder' icon. use it to upload/download file to colab vm

Comment: Thanks, but I 100% know how to do this technically.
What I am curious is that where should I put it.